# Browser cache in JHipster Application (NGINX + Spring Boot + VueJs)

Tags: nginx, vuejs2, jhipster

I've developed an Application using JHipster (Spring Boot and VueJS) and put it behind a NGINX to reverse proxy all incoming 80 and 443 requests to port 8080.
The Profile "prod" postfixes all resources with a hashcode, so that only the latest versions loaded.
My Problem is that after every deployment the page is shown cluttered and it looks like that browser tries to load old css and js files without success.
After a hard reset (Shift+F5) all resources will be loaded and the page shown correctly.
But I cannot ask every user to hit Shift+F5 once I deploy the Server.

Any Help to solve my serious Problem is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read this article? https://medium.com/@codemonk/automatic-reload-of-client-after-deploying-in-vue-js-91c120f85f0e I don't know Vue but this is a classical problem, same with Angular. You could submit a feature request to JHipster project and maybe contribute it.

Comment: Thank you for Link @GaëlMarziou It is interesting indeed but my Problem is that even after a manual reload (F5) the content remains old till I do a hard reload with Shift+F5

Comment: This can happen only if index.htm is not refreshed because (as you noticed) the other resources are postfixed with a hashcode. So you should check whether the problem exists without nginx and also look at the cache headers of index.htm response.

Comment: Good point @GaëlMarziou. I have posted my solution below. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have ended up with this Configuration:

```
upstream api {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
    server_name myserver.com      www.myserver.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/css application/javascript application/json image/svg+xml;
    gzip_comp_level 9;
    etag on;

    proxy_redirect    off;
    proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    location /content {
        proxy_pass http://api/content;
        add_header Cache-Control max-age=31536000;
    }

    location /i18n {
        proxy_pass http://api/i18n;
        add_header Cache-Control max-age=31536000;
    }

    location /app {
        proxy_pass http://api/app;
        add_header Cache-Control max-age=31536000;
    }

    location /index.html {
        proxy_pass http://api/index.html;
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    }

    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        alias /var/www/acme-challenge/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://api;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```